# How to return an object property through a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a simple object and I want to call a particular property by passing a property name through a function:

```
spit(name);

function spit(value) {
    var test = new Object();
    test.name = "Bill";
    test.number = 24;
    console.log(test.value);
}
```

The above code should return "Bill". How is this possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confused with arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
spit('name');

function spit(value) {
    var test = new Object();
    test.name = "Bill";
    test.number = 24;
    console.log(test[value]);
}
```

Comment: This works, but only when I call the function with value as a string. `spit('name')`. Thanks! Was having a brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `value` property, which has not been defined for the object. Also, you aren't quoting your parameter when calling `spit()`, which might be a problem.

Try using this:

```
function spit(value) {
    var test = new Object();
    test.name = "Bill";
    test.number = 24;
    console.log(test[value]);
}

spit('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function spit(value) {
    var test = {
       name: 'Bill',
       number: 24
    }

    test[value] = value;

    return test.value;   
}
```